# Understanding an Estimator Identity

Tags: regression, estimators

[image: ![Link of Identity]

I came across this in my textbook, and am having trouble understanding why these two things are equal.  Is there an identity someone could show me to help me understand? It seems like we're dropping $\bar{Y}$ and $\bar{X}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know that the sum of mean deviations is identically zero, i.e.

$$\sum \left(X_i - \bar{X} \right) = 0$$

That is the only identity you need to prove both results. Expand, use the properties of the sum and simplify whenever possible. We are dropping $\bar{Y}$ and $\bar{X}$ because they can be moved out of the summation as they are constants.

Comment: Iff $\bar{X}$ is defined. A typical counterexample is the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Comment: You can define the sample mean for all distributions.